# Rsync not using the date suffix correctly

Tags: batch-file, rsync

I am attempting to set up Rsync to backup an offsite computer to a server using Rsync. The basics of this I have down without an issue, although I have finally hit a road block.

The rsync batch file on the workstation looks like this: (testing this locally before I implement it on a remote server)
C:\rsync\rsync.exe -brutz --suffix=.old "/cygdrive/C/location of file/test_1.txt" "/cygdrive/C/location of test folder/test folder/"

The batch file works like a charm, allowing me to change the file "test_1.txt" if it has changed to using the suffix of .old.

In the folder I have "test_1.txt" and "text_1.txt.old"

The issue occurs if I change the --suffix from .old to using a date format:

--suffix=_`date +"%m%d%Y_%H%M"`

OR

--suffix=_`date +%F`

Rsync will attempt to find a file named "+F'" in the backup directory
It will backup "text_1.txt" and change the old file to "test_1.txt_'date"

I have looked around google a bit and have not found any solutions. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The term `"%m%d%Y_%H%M"` isn't a batch file method of specifying a date or time stamp.

If it is an Rsync term then you may have success by doubling the percent signs

`"%%m%%d%%Y_%%H%%M"`

Answer (score 0):

`--suffix=".$(date +%F)"` should work